# What is mons in extjs. How will you explain mons in Extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to retrieve the value which I entered in my filter. Although I am able to get that I found on attribute in `inputItem` of dataindex which I wanted to retrieve, called `mons` which is array and consist few dom objects. I am not getting what exactly is that.

Can anybody please explain me what is `mons`

Comment: In what version? AFAIK it's not a public API thing, so if you want to check it out you have all the source.

Comment: I am using 3.4 ExtJS. I want to retrieve entered value in filter.

Comment: At first I read "What is moms".. lol

Comment: @aMazing Ok, Hope you visit optometrist place this weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mon : Adds listeners to any Observable object (or Elements) which are automatically removed when this Component is destroyed.

Example :

```
myGridPanel.mon(myGridPanel.getSelectionModel(), 'selectionchange',     handleSelectionChange, null, {buffer: 50});
```

It return void.

Here is [doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-mon) You will understand once you read.

Comment: Thanks for detail info.